# How to hide the symbol $ when highlighting LaTeX equations in Emacs Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I know that in Org-mode, the emphasis markers like `*, ~, =, +, _` can be hidden by this setting: `(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)`.

I wonder if there is any option that enables hiding the markers like `$` or `\(`, `\)` of LaTeX?

This will be useful when LaTeX math equations can be highlighted by setting:
`(setq org-highlight-latex-and-related '(latex script entities))`

---

**Update 1**

I tried the solution proposed by @Thomas on a fresh `emacs -q` but somehow the symbol `$` is still not hidden, while other markers like `*,+` are. \

Not sure if there is something wrong with my Emacs? I'm using Org 9.3 of Emacs 27.1

---

**Update 2**

The solution of Thomas does work for Emacs 25.2!

But somehow, there is a major change in Emacs 26.2, 26.3, 27.1 that breaks this feature... :(

---

**Update 3**

Since the solution suggested by Thomas doesn't work with recent Emacs (26 or newer), I finally came up with a quick solution by customizing the function `org-do-latex-and-related` of Org-mode.

```lisp
(defun org-do-latex-and-related (_limit)
  "Highlight LaTeX snippets and environments, entities and sub/superscript.
Stop at first highlighted object, if any.  Return t if some
highlighting was done, nil otherwise."
  (when (org-string-nw-p org-latex-and-related-regexp)
    (catch 'found
      (while (re-search-forward org-latex-and-related-regexp
                                        nil t) ;; on purpose, we ignore LIMIT
    (unless (cl-some (lambda (f) (memq f '(org-code org-verbatim underline
                            org-special-keyword)))
             (save-excursion
               (goto-char (1+ (match-beginning 0)))
               (face-at-point nil t)))
      (let* ((offset (if (memq (char-after (1+ (match-beginning 0)))
                   '(?_ ?^))
                 1
               0))
         (start (+ offset (match-beginning 0)))
         (end (match-end 0)))
        (if (memq 'native org-highlight-latex-and-related)
              (org-src-font-lock-fontify-block "latex" start end)
          (font-lock-prepend-text-property start end
                                                   'face 'org-latex-and-related))
      ;;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      ;; my code starts here
      (when (and org-hide-emphasis-markers (< (+ start 4) end))
        (cond ((member (buffer-substring start (+ start 2)) '("$$" "\\("))
               (add-text-properties start (+ start 2) '(invisible org-link)))
              ((string= (buffer-substring (1+ start) (+ start 2)) "$")
               (add-text-properties (1+ start) (+ start 2) '(invisible org-link))))
        (cond ((member (buffer-substring end (- end 2)) '("$$" "\\)"))
               (add-text-properties end (- end 2) '(invisible org-link)))
              ((string= (buffer-substring (1- end) (- end 2)) "$")
               (add-text-properties (1- end) (- end 2) '(invisible org-link)))))
      ;; my code ends here
      ;;>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        (add-text-properties (+ offset (match-beginning 0)) (match-end 0)
                                   '(font-lock-multiline t)))
      (throw 'found t)))
      nil)))
```

If anyone interested in this feature, you can place the above function somewhere in your Emacs configuration file, after Org-mode is loaded, so that the new `org-do-latex-and-related` will override the original one of Org-mode.

Here is what I obtained using the code above:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to not hide the $ symbol at all and instead use [org-fragtog](https://github.com/io12/org-fragtog). It automatically toggles org-mode latex fragment previews as the cursor enters and exits them.

However, when you open a file with equations it will only toggle the preview of an equation as the cursor enters and leaves the equation. I also have a keybinding (f5) for `org-latex-preview`. If I open an org-mode file with many equations I can type `C-u C-u f5` to toggle latex preview on all equations in the buffer. If I want to change some equation I can just move the cursor there and `org-fragtog-mode` will turn-off the preview. Then I can edit the equation and the cursor leaves the equation the preview will be automatically enabled again.

This also works correctly when `org-highlight-latex-and-related` is set to any of the possible choices as well as when you use prettify-symbols-mode.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! This is also a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Customize the variable `org-emphasis-alist` and add `$` as an additional maker with the default values for all customization options. To do so, type

```
M-x customize-variable [RET] org-emphasis-alist [RET]
```

Then go to the bottom of the customization buffer, click on the last `INS`, and insert a dollar sign under `Marker character:`.

Finally, click on `State` to make this change permanent either for the current editing session only or also for all future sessions.

**NOTE** that you have to restart org-mode by typing `M-x org-mode` again in order for this change to take effect.

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't work. Does it work with your Emacs?

Comment: Yes, it does. Did you remember to restart `org-mode` in the relevant buffer in order for this chance to take effect? To be safe, you could restart all of Emacs, too.

Comment: `M-x org-reload` should do it.

Comment: @Thomas: I tried your solution on a fresh `emacs -q` but it still didn't work. I attached a screenshot in the update of my post. What is the version of your Emacs and Org?

Comment: Emacs: 25.2.2; org-mode: 8.2.10 -- I just tried with `emacs -q` and all I need to do is set `org-hide-emphasis-markers` to `t` (like in your question) and add `$` to `org-emphasis-alist` (like in my answer) and it works. Sorry to hear it doesn't for you. Did you try `M-x revert-buffer` after `M-x org-reload`?

Comment: Yes, I also closed my org file and opened it again but it didn't work. I also tried Emacs 26.2 and Org 9.1, and it didn't work either. I'm not sure why. Maybe there were some major changes in the new version of Org... Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Oh, man, too bad. Could you just try if the following works? Start emacs like this: `emacs -q --eval "(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t org-emphasis-alist '((\"\$\" bold)))" /tmp/test.org` -- when I run that command and insert a LaTeX math expression in `$` signs, they get marked as bold and the `$`s get hidden.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your code snippet!! This time, I installed Emacs-25.2 and it successfully hide the `$` symbol. But NOT with Emacs 26.2, 26.3, 27.1. So, I confirm that there is a major change in the new Emacs that breaks this feature of Emacs 25.2